# Is casting from char * to other compatibly-aligned pointer types defined behavior in C89?

Tags: c, casting, language-lawyer, c89, strict-aliasing

Are explicit casts from `char *` to other pointer types fully defined behavior according to ANSI C89 if the pointer is guaranteed to meet the alignment requirements of the type you're casting to? Here's an example of what I mean:

```c
/* process.c */
void *process(size_t elem_size, size_t cap) {
    void *arr;
    assert(cap > 5);
    arr = malloc(elem_size * cap);
    /* set id of element 5 to 0xffffff */
    *(long *)((char *)arr + elem_size*5) = 0xffffff;
    /* rest of the code omitted */
    return arr;
}

/* main.c */
struct some_struct  { long id; /* other members omitted */ };
struct other_struct { long id; /* other members omitted */ };
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct some_struct *s = process(sizeof(struct some_struct), 40);
    printf("%lx\n", s[5].id);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles without warnings and works as expected on my machine but I'm not fully sure if these kinds of casts are defined behavior.

[C89 draft, section 4.10.3 (Memory management functions)](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.10.3):

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object and then used to access such an object in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly freed or reallocated).

[C89 draft, section 3.3.4 (Cast operators)](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3.4):

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type or a different incomplete type. The resulting pointer might not be valid if it is improperly aligned for the type pointed to. It is guaranteed, however, that a pointer to an object of a given alignment may be converted to a pointer to an object of the same alignment or a less strict alignment and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

This clearly specifies what happens if you cast from `struct some_struct *` to `char *` and back to `struct some_struct *` but in my case the code responsible for allocation doesn't have access to the full struct definition so it can't initially specify the pointer type to be `struct some_struct *` so I'm not sure if the rule still applies.

If the code I posted is technically UB, is there another standards-compliant way to modify array elements without knowing their full type? Are there real-world impementations where you would expect it to do something else than `((struct some_struct *)arr)[5].id = 0xffffff;`?

Comment: Consider replacing ansi-c with language-lawyer tag

Comment: IIRC in C89 pointer arithmetic over a malloc'd array (and thus indexing) was technically UB anyway, and nobody cared.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: All that would have been needed to fix the "strict aliasing" rule would have been to recognize that (1) the rule should only apply if storage is used as multiple types in some particular context, which may be drawn broadly or narrowly at the compiler's convenience, and (2) if a compiler that is looking in a context at drawn least as broadly as for #1 can see that a pointer or lvalue of one type is used to derive a pointer or lvalue of another, it should recognize that the derived pointer might be used to access something of the original type.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I don't think any of the people who approved the Standard ever imagined that it would be taken as an invitation for compilers to be willfully blind as to how pointers are derived.  The wheels fell off with the nonsensical rationale given for the answer to DR#028, which got codified as the "Effective Type" rule whose corner cases cannot be handled properly without making an absurd amount of effort and/or foregoing what should be useful optimizations.  Apply the rules above to the DR#028 example, however, and it would have answered it cleanly.

Answer (score 2):

> This code compiles without warnings and works as expected on my machine but I'm not fully sure if these kinds of casts are defined behavior.

In general, *the casts* have defined behavior, but that behavior can be that the result is not a valid pointer.  Thus *dereferencing the result* of the cast may produce UB.

Considering only function `process()`, then, it is possible that the result of its evaluation of `(long *)((char *)arr + elem_size*5)` is an invalid pointer.  If and only if it is invalid, the attempt to use it to assign a value to the object it hypothetically points to produces UB.

However, `main()`s particular usage of that function is fine:

- In `process()`, the pointer returned by `malloc` and stored in `arr` is suitably aligned for a `struct some_struct` (and for any other type).
- The compiler must choose a size and layout for `struct some_struct` such that every element and every member of every element of an array of such structures is properly aligned.
- Arrays are composed of contiguous objects of the array's element type, without gaps (though the element types themselves may contain padding if they are structures or unions).
- Therefore, `(char *)arr + n * sizeof(struct some_struct)` must be suitably aligned for a `struct some_struct`, for any integer `n` such that the result points within or just past the end of the allocated region.  This computation is closely related to the computations involved in accessing an array of `struct some_struct` via the indexing operator.
- `struct some_struct` has a `long` as its first member, and that member must appear at offset 0 from the beginning of the struct.  Therefore, every pointer that is suitably aligned for a `struct some_struct` must also be suitably aligned for a `long`.

Comment: "it is possible that the result of its evaluation of `(long *)((char *)arr + elem_size*5)` is an invalid pointer."

Assuming all callers of `process()` would pass an `elem_size` of `sizeof(long)`, `sizeof(array of longs)` or `sizeof(struct with long as first member)`, would there still be a possibility of  `(long *)((char *)arr + elem_size*5)` evaluating to an invalid pointer?

Comment: @mio, please read the rest of this answer, especially "`main()`s particular usage of that function is fine".

Answer (score 0):

Determining whether an operation upholds or violates "type aliasing" constraints requires being able to answer two questions:

1. For purposes of the aliasing rules, when does a region of storage hold an "object" of a particular type.
2. For purposes of the aliasing rules, is a particular access performed "by" an lvalue expression of a particular type.

For your question, the second issue above is the most the relevant: if a pointer or lvalue of type `T1` is used to derive a value of type `T2*` which is dereferenced to access storage, the access may sometimes need to be regarded for purposes of aliasing as though performed by an lvalue of type `T1`, and sometimes as though performed by one of type `T2`, but the Standard fails to offer any guidance as to which interpretation should apply when.  Constructs like yours would be processed predictably by implementation that didn't abuse the Standard as an excuse to behave nonsensically, but could be processed nonsensically by conforming but obtuse implementations that do abuse the Standard in such fashion.

The authors of C89 didn't expect anyone to care about the precise boundaries between constructs whose behavior was defined by the Standard, versus those which all implementations were expected to process identically but which the Standard didn't actually define, and thus saw no need to define the terms "object" and "by" with sufficient precision to unambiguously answer the above questions in ways that would yield defined program behavior in all sensible cases.